# Transform List<Map<String,String>> with "," separated String values using java 8 stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I need a way to transform the below mentioned JSON into List> using java 8 streams. There a a few challenges here, there are a few attributes that I need and need to ignore the rest. I need weight and product basically.

```
[
        {weight=30, type=cosmatic, product=product-1,product-2,product-3}, 
        {weight=15, type=commercia, product=product-1,product-3}, 
        {weight=50, ramdonField=newValue, product=product-1,product-4}, 
        {weight=2,  product=product-1,product-2}, 
        {weight=15, product=product-1}, 
        {weight=25, product=product-1}, 
        {weight=2,  product=product-1}
    ]
```

I was able to achieve this by writing the below code, Just wanted to know if there is a more efficient way of doing this.

```
    List<Map<String, Object>> franchiseRulesTemp = new LinkedList<>();
    for (Entry<String, Object> test : config.entrySet()) {
                try {
                    if (test.getValue() instanceof Map<?, ?> && ((Map<String, Object>) test.getValue()).containsKey("product")) {
                        Map<String, Object> mapper = ((Map<String, Object>) test.getValue());
                        String productList = (String) mapper.get("product");
                        String[] productListArray = productList.split(",");
                        for (String product : productListArray) {
                            Map<String, Object> gameDetails = new HashMap<>();
                            gameDetails.putAll((Map<String, Object>) test.getValue());
                            gameDetails.put("product",product);
                            gameDetails.put("ruleName", test.getKey());
                            franchiseRulesTemp.add(gameDetails);
                        }
                    } 
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    System.out.println("Occured" + exception.getMessage());
                }
            }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: But really, you should start thinking interms of classes and objects, instead of thinking in terms of maps. Define a class with two typed properties `weight` and `product` and use that instead of using maps.

Comment: @user2681668, you have added extra requirements, we still don't see any of your attempts. Take care to add some.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of this should suffice:

```
List<Map<String, String>> resultSet = 
          myList.stream()
                .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet()
                               .stream()
                               .flatMap(e -> Arrays.stream(e.getValue().split(","))
                               .map(a -> Map.of(e.getKey(), a))))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Update:**

After your edit, I'd recommend that you create a custom class with the properties `weight`, `type`, `product` and so forth. Spin up however many objects required populating it with the necessary data and store them in a list.

When you need a result from the list then you can stream over the list of your custom objects then collect to a map extracting the weights of the custom objects and their product property.

Your current approach using a `List<Map<String, String>>` unfortunately is not a good approach to proceed with.

Comment: `weight=30` will be no longer attached to each of split parts, there won't be maps like `{weight=30, product=product-1}`

Comment: @Andrew this solution assumes the format is in `List<Map<String, String>> myList = new ArrayList<>();
        HashMap<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();
        myMap.put("30","product-1,product-2,product-3");
        HashMap<String, String> myMap1 = new HashMap<>();
        myMap1.put("15","product-1,product-3");
        HashMap<String, String> myMap2 = new HashMap<>();
        myMap2.put("50","product-1,product-4"); ...` etc.  which would yield the correct output of `[{30=product-1}, {30=product-2}` etc.. repeating "weight=" and "product=" in every entry is just redundant IMO.

Comment: @Andrew now that the OP has edited the post, it makes my previous comment no longer valid as "apparently" it's not just a map of "weight" and "product" which should have been mentioned in the first place not when people starting answering...

Comment: "Cannot infer type argument(s) for <R> flatMap(Function<? super T,? extends Stream<? extends R>>)" this is the error that is throwing upon using this.

Comment: @user2681668 working fine for me... try using explicit parameter types e.g. `myList.stream()
                        .flatMap((Map<String, String> map) -> map.entrySet()
                                .stream()
                                .flatMap((Map.Entry<String, String> e) -> Arrays.stream(e.getValue().split(","))
                                        .map(a -> Map.of(e.getKey(), a))))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());`